# Install Freetype library module for PHP on XAMPP in Windows

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

how to install Freetype library modules.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

> Keep in mind that attempting to set magic_quotes_gpc at runtime will not work.

If you can't find that setting in the php.ini, than magic quotes are off by default. I guess what you want is to turn it on, right?

If so, then just go ahead and add the line `magic_gpc_quotes = 1` to your php.ini and you'll be fine.

If the opposite is true and you can't write to the php.ini then look for code that undos the escaping: http://www.charles-reace.com/blog/2010/07/13/undoing-magic-quotes/.

As for the freetype library, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205825.

Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. is it ok if i add the line magic_gpc_quotes = 0( for turning off) in php.ini. in which line shall i add this. thanks once again

Comment: It is ok to add it and any line would do. Just make sure you put it on a line of its own.